# Sound immediately crashes on playback

Tags: audio, alsa, pop-os, pipewire

**My problem :**
Sound stops working immediately after like 1.5 seconds when I try to play a sound (from the "test" button in the sound settings)
The System76 website provides troubleshooting help for pulseaudio but Pop!_OS moved to pipewire since version 22.04

**Infos on my setup :**
I'm running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64 on an Asus Zenbook UX430UNR 1.0
I'm using Pipewire (default on Pop!_OS 22.04)
I had this issue like a month ago when I installed pop and somehow fixed it until now
To my best knowledge, I didn't do anything special for it to break

**What I tried :**
‣ Reboot
‣ Install proprietary media codecs following [this guide](https://support.system76.com/articles/codecs/)
‣ Restart alsa (alsactl init)
‣ Checked allowed sample rates in pipewire.conf but don't know anything about this
‣ `journalctl --user --unit pipewire-pulse` and `journalctl --user --unit pipewire` but got `No entries` (Also tried with `.service`)
‣ Checked that auto mute is disabled in aslamixer

**Observations :**
‣ When I reboot or restart alsa (alsactl init), there's sound for a moment but it either stops after a few seconds or is really bad, or both
‣ When I unmute the "headphones" entry in alsamixer, the sound reappears but is very crappy
‣ My current """workaround""" is to run `amixer set Headphone mute && amixer set Headphone unmute` every second with `watch`, this makes the sound work most of the time. I want to stress that I'm not using headphones.

EDIT : I now think it broke when I switched to windows and then back to pop (dual boot), doing it again seems to fix the problem, any ideas on what's happening / how to avoid having to switch twice every time?

Comment: Try running Fedora 36 in Live mode. It has a much newer/fresher kernel and audio server.

Comment: Could it fix the problem or is it for diagnosis? Because I also have Debian and Windows installed in dual boot and everything works fine for them

Comment: Now that I think of it I think it broke when I switched to windows and then back to pop, I hadn't done it since I installed pop

Comment: Maybe I should rewrite a new question considering the "new problem"?